# Stack Overflow flair is returning incorrect reputation for clean theme only

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, flair

I am trying to use the [Stack Overflow flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353), but only the clean theme is not returning the proper reputation. Is there a problem with this tag?

Clean Theme:

> [image]

Others Themes [Returning proper values of reputation]

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

What I see:

> [image]

Comment: I have cleared my brower cache, still see same problem with clear. Moreover if it is cached it should happen for remaining aswell, right?

Comment: Anna was talking about the server cache, not the browser cache. It is not in your control. IIRC, the server cache is cleared up weekly.

Comment: If you're so worried about your privacy delete your account, don't ask something then edit it so it's meaningless.

Comment: @Lance yeah, the OP is really fighting to remove the flair for some very odd reason that's why so many edits.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I was just surprised by your rollback to #2 right after you did the rollback to #3.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I thought #3 was the last good revision then noticed it has broken images, thought #2 had them fixed, still broken so ended up fixing it myself.

Answer (score 4):

Flairs are cached, so it probably just didn't update yet. I see the correct rep when I look at the clean version of your flair.

Comment: The cache is also specific to the server you hit (so one person will see the issue, when others will not). As a note, this probably happens because the clean theme flair is used elsewhere (on a blog, for instance), so will be cached before you visit the flair page.

Comment: Got it, I will recheck after sometime.